# Angular Routing Not Working After Upgrading to Angular 4

Tags: angular, platform-server

I updated like this, [found here](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html)

> On Linux/Mac:  npm install
>   @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest
>   typescript@latest --save

When I remove node_modules and then `npm install` I get this,

> WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 5889:15-36 Critical
>   dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Maybe this will help someone help me. It appears to be an issue with ES5?

Current errors in console.

[image]

**Background**

My project was working fine till I upgraded to `Angular 4` last night. Now when I click on a link instead of loading the module (I am lazy loading) it tells me it cannot find the module.

**Eror**

> ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>   Error: Cannot find module './benefits/benefits.module'. Error: Cannot
>   ……}

Has anyone else shared this situation or have any clue how to fix this or even what to do to go about troubleshooting it? I thought there were no breaking changes in `Angular 4`?

**Code Examples**

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "my-web-application",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.2.0",
    "auth0-lock": "^10.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.3.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^2.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.32.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: what are the steps you followed to update to angular4

Comment: I updated question

Comment: What is your final Angular-cli version?

Comment: I upgraded to latest Globally and then I installed locally before installing package json. I ended up with this and it worked so I have not touched it, "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across some of the errors that you have pictured while upgrading to Angular 4.0:

> `Critical dependency: The request of the dependency is an expression.`

Updating angluar-cli to latest solved that for me:

1. Stop `ng serve` (if running).
2. `npm install @angular/cli@latest --save-dev`
3. `ng serve`

Hopefully, this fixes your zone.js issue as well (keep me posted, please).

The warning:

> `The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead...`

is most likely caused by a library (possibly `ng2-bootstrap`, `ng2-charts`, or `ng2-toasty`?) that's using the deprecated `template` syntax (or you are in your code), so you may want to try to upgrade those as well -- if there is a newer version.  I also got this deprecation warning, but I have a dependency that still hasn't been updated to 4.0, so I'm living with it for the next few days.

**Note**: I wasn't a big fan of those [upgrade instructions](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html) as following them verbatim (like I originally did, without paying attention) on some projects gives you both `dependencies` and `devDependencies` that reference to different versions of the same lib.  For example, *you* now have two versions of `@angular/compiler-cli` referenced in your `package.json`: `4.0` and `2.4`.

**Update for Completeness**

Unfortunately, in [wuno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2218253)'s case, to complete the upgrade, he had to go as far as:

1. Create a new project.
2. Update it.
3. Replace the `src` directory with the one from his existing project.
4. `npm install` and update `package.json` with his extra packages.

Per his final comment:

> I had to create a new project, update it, replace the src directory
>   with the one from my existing project then npm install and update
>   package.json with my extra packages.

We never quite found out *what* was causing the issue that forced him to *re-create the project* in his particular case, but upgrading CLI ultimately fixed the issue in the original question.

Comment: G yes I was thinking that would solve it as well. But it did not solve it for me.

Comment: @wuno Are you still experiencing all of the same warnings/errors or have some been cleared up after the CLI update?

Comment: Well I just realized my problem now is I cant get ng serve to run since I updated. I get Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (/Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/node/riverwalk-web-application/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/serve.js:22:61)
    at /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/node/riverwalk-web-application/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/serve.run.js:22:22
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Comment: @wuno If you haven't seen this yet, it may be helpful: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4736 Check for the leading "." In the file name of angular-cli.json. It changed in later versions of CLI.

Comment: Hey man I updated angular cli globally and locally and could not get the project to run. So I created a new project with ng new and the package.json file shows,"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",,  So now my project is running with no errors,  "@angular/common": "^2.3.1", But I thought the current version of angular cli was 1.0.0 ?? Do you see what I mean? My plan was to start upgrade process with angular cli already upgraded to see if that helps, but the version of angular cli in package.json does not seem to be recent.

Comment: OK so it compiles with only one error now, ERROR in ./src/app/contract/contract.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms/src/model I am hoping if I clear this it will run. but I did not read anything about forms changing in angular 4. Did you see anything about this anywhere? import { VALID }  from "@angular/forms/src/model"; Is causing the error.

Comment: Yes that is how i have been importing VALID to check for VALID in my form. It works fine till I upgraded. But I cant find any reference of this online.

Comment: https://www.insight.io/github.com/angular/angular/blob/g3_v2_0/modules/@angular/forms/src/model.ts

Comment: Weirdly I check for the file and it does Exist... also I can open it and see VALID defined inside of it... /**
 * Indicates that a FormControl is valid, i.e. that no errors exist in the input value.
 */
export declare const VALID = "VALID";
/**

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't worked with ngForms that much, so I don't think I'd be too useful here, but might I suggest commenting that code out temporarily (if possible) to see if ng serve builds and runs before going any deeper in that rabbit hole. It would suck to fix that issue just to find out that this was all for nothing.

Comment: Ya good point. I think it will work. Thanks I will accept your answer give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok your right man it worked. It was a little more to it. I had to create a new project, update it, replace the src directory with the one from my existing project then npm install and update package.json with my extra packages. But good call bro and thanks. The VALID thing is a different issue obviously. I just don't understand cause there were not supposed to be any breaking changes. I suggest maybe you add my steps, but it is obviously up to you! Have a good night man!

Comment: For me the UI framework PrimeNG was the problem: [PrimeNG routing issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2420#issuecomment-291116384)